# Visual Studio UML Model

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, uml

Is there a way to import .net data types into the UML modeler in Visual Studio.  I attempted to add references but that did not solve the issue.

Also if I am modeling for .net is there any reason for simple class diagrams that I would not use the class diagram .net tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are able to manually type a data type into the "Type" property for a class attribute in a UML diagram.  If you then select the "Generate Code" option from within the UML Explorer, the generated class uses the data type associated with the class attribute.
Link: [How to Generate Code from UML Class Diagrams](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff657795.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

If you have an MSDN subscription, you can download the [Visual Studio 2010 Feature Pack 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/vstudio/ff655021.aspx), which lets you drag .NET types from Architecture Explorer to a UML class diagram, adding them to the UML Model Explorer. For more info, see [How to: Create UML Class Diagrams from Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff657806.aspx).